# Does a general InnoDB UPDATE lock the entire table and block incoming specific UPDATEs?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb, innodb, table-locking

Suppose I ran this statement:

```
UPDATE Employees set country='AU'
```

On an InnoDB table, Employees, with about 10 million rows.

This table is also actively being updated by other users through SQL queries like the one below:

E.g. a User, ID = 20, changes their country to NZ:

```
UPDATE Employees set country='NZ' where id = 20
```

1. In that case, will any further updates to this table block until the
   general update completes?
2. If so, is there a way to allow specific
   updates and the general update to run concurrently, if they are not
   updating the same row? (To clarify what I mean here: suppose the
   general update finishes updating Employees with Id 1 - 50, and is
   now updating Emplyoees 51 - ~10 million, a singular update on
   Employee with id of 20 should go through without waiting for the
   general update to finish)

Comment: It is quite abnormal to change _all_ rows of a table with a single `UPDATE`.  Why have the `country` column if the table is used only for Australia?

Comment: Sorry, country may not be a good example. In production, we are always resetting certain counters to zero for all users on a daily basis.

Comment: 50M rows?  Does the counter get updated more than once per day?  (If not, there is a trivial workaround.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the first update will place exclusive locks on all records in the table, blocking other queries from updating it. The locks are held until the transaction is commited.
2. No. The locks are held while the transaction is running and a released when the transaction is commited. You may want to update the table in chuncks, rather than in one big bang, avoiding the first update locking the entire table. Or execute the update outside of business hours, if possible.

Comment: Suppose business hours is 24/7, then the chunk approach is most optimal? There are no other ways around this locking issue?

Comment: As I wrote, the locks are exclusive. Only one transaction can hold it on a record at a time.

Comment: I'll approve your answer, but may I know your sources that the lock is a table lock?

Comment: @lbj99 - DMLs do only _row_ locks;  DDLs may do _table_ locks.

Comment: @lbj99 all rows in the table will be locked, since there is no where clause in your update to filter out any records.

Answer (score 0):

Let's "think out of the box"...

Have 2 columns.  One with the `counter`; one (`dy`) with the `DATE` of the last increment of the counter.  Then make the bumping of the counter a little more complex -- namely to reset it to 1 if the date is before today.  Also (always) update the date to `CURDATE()`.

Something like

```
UPDATE t
    SET counter = IF (dy = CURDATE(), counter + 1, 1),
        dy = CURDATE()
    WHERE id = 123
```

This *eliminates* the big, nightly, update.

To fetch the counter *for the current day*,

```
SELECT  IF (dy = CURDATE(), counter, 0) AS counter
    WHERE id = 123;
```

This technique also avoids having to run the big update at exactly midnight.  And a second-order "bug" if the machine happened to be down at midnight (and the update fails to get run for the day).